# How to show and hide image in Item List control in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a list control and each item contains two images and text. On the click on each item I want to hide or show selected image on selected list item.

Here is XAML code snippet:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="list" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="None"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="None"  
                               Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility, 
                            Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C# code:

```
 dataSource = new ObservableCollection<ImageData>() 
        { 
        new ImageData(){Name = "User1:", ImagePath="/Images/user1.png", ImageVisibility = false},
        new ImageData(){Name = "User1:", ImagePath="/Images/user1.png", ImageVisibility = true},
        new ImageData(){Name = "User1:", ImagePath="/Images/user1.png", ImageVisibility = true},
        new ImageData(){Name = "User2:", ImagePath="/Images/user2.png", ImageVisibility = true}
        };
```

List Selection Changed Event:

```
        private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ImageData)(((object[])(e.AddedItems))[0])).ImageVisibility = false;
        list.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

ImageData class:

```
 public class ImageData
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool ImageVisibility { get; set; }
    }
```

Image Visibility Converter:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            flag = (bool)value;
        }
        else if (value is bool?)
        {
            bool? nullable = (bool?)value;
            flag = nullable.HasValue ? nullable.Value : false;
        }
        return (flag ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((value is Visibility) && (((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible));
    }

}
```

Please help me to accomplish such functionality.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on what you are trying to do. I don't understand why you have two same images per item and which one are you trying to hide and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use INotifyPropertyChanged interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

For example so:

```
public class ImageData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _imageVisibility;
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ImageVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _imageVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageVisibility");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Full changes according to your task you can see [here (dropbox)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31216763/PhoneApp1.rar)

Comment: Thanks Lumen!! It is a answered.